# SQLiteAssetHelper NullPointerException problem

Tags: java, android

I am using SqliteAssetHelper to copy my database from assets folder.
But I am getting NullPointerException. The strange thing is that it is happening on some devices not on all devices, I never got it on emulator or my test device but I am getting it on my play console crashes reports. Following are the details, please help me thanks in advance. Please note that firsrname and secondname mentioned below are parts of my app id

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity    (ActivityThread.java:2412)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2607)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1325)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5756)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo (ContextWrapper.java:165)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init> (SQLiteAssetHelper.java:109)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init> (SQLiteAssetHelper.java:129)
at com.firstname.secondname.firstnamesecondname.DatabaseHelperClass.<init> (DatabaseHelperClass.java:24)
at com.firstname.secondname.firstnamesecondname.DatabaseAccessClass.<init> (DatabaseAccessClass.java:24)
at com.firstname.secondname.firstnamesecondname.DatabaseAccessClass.getInstance (DatabaseAccessClass.java:35)
at com.firstname.secondname.firstnamesecondname.ActivityName.<init> (ActivityName.java:29
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2403)
```

**my project class is**

```
public class ActivityName extends AppCompatActivity {

CheckBox checkbtn;
String abc;
DatabaseAccessClass databaseAccess = DatabaseAccessClass.getInstance(this); //(Please note This is line number 29 in ActivityName)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_name);

    databaseAccess.open();

    Cursor cname = databaseAccess.getDetails(abc);
    cname.moveToFirst();
    String itemname = cname.getString(8);
    TextView iname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inametv);
    compname.setText(itemname);
    cname.close();

    //to add the current value to recent table
    addValueRecent();

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.maintab);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),ActivityName.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    databaseAccess.close();
}

public void addValueRecent(){

    databaseAccess.open();
    databaseAccess.insertValuerecent(abc);

    Cursor getallrecentb = databaseAccess.getAllRecentValues();

    if (getallrecentb.getCount()>20){

        getallrecentb.moveToLast();
        String id = getallrecentb.getString(0);
        databaseAccess.deleteValuerecent(id);
    }
    getallrecentb.close();
    databaseAccess.close();

}
```

**DatabaseAccessClass Line no 35 is**

```
public static DatabaseAccessClass getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {

        instance = new DatabaseAccessClass(context);//(this is line no 35 in DatabaseAccessClass)
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Don't call `DatabaseAccessClass.getInstance(this)` in a field initializer; i.e., in the line you have it now. Move that into your `onCreate()` override, sometime after the `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: Thanks Mike M. It was so helpful, I am really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
DatabaseAccessClass databaseAccess = DatabaseAccessClass.getInstance(this);
```

You have to update your code as follows:

```
DatabaseAccessClass databaseAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_name);
    databaseAccess = DatabaseAccessClass.getInstance(this);
    ...
}
```

Also, here:

```
instance = new DatabaseAccessClass(context);
```

Try to get the application's context.. like:

```
instance = new DatabaseAccessClass(context.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, for detailed answer, it was really helpful.